# Reading file as stream with puppteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I need to read some files from a site where each file should be read as a stream.
I tried many approaches but it seems I do something wrong. I manage to download the file but didnt find how to read them.

- I want to inform you that there is a security block that I don't understand how to overcome it.
- Got to say that the page is completely public and by law, it should allow people like me to scrape the data (But the website designer makes it very hard for me due to they not bend the law)

To the code(I tried to avoid unnecessary lines )

```
const scrapeAndReadFiles = async (url,username) => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(...options);
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  
  try {
    await page.goto(url + "/login?r=%2Ffile", {});
    let pages = await browser.pages(); 
    let loginPage = pages[pages.length - 1];

    await performLogin(loginPage ) // custom func that use waitForSelector etc to the loginpage
   
    await page.authenticate({ username });
    const cookieCert = await page.cookies();

    // page one redirect me to page2 where i do the scrape
    const page2 = await browser.newPage();
    await page2.setCookie(...cookieCert);
    await page2.goto(url+"file");
    await page2.waitForSelector("td");
    
    const fileUrlArray = await page2.$$eval("tr td a", (files) => {
      return files.map((link) => {
          return link.getAttribute("href");
      });
    });

   // fileUrlArray store the desired links for me but its seems i cant get any response from 
   //  those files , i dont understand why (in the next example i just try get res for one 
   // file

    // --------------------- Non Working block ----------------------------
    const page3 = await browser.newPage();
    await page3.setCookie(...cookieCert);
    const res = await page3.goto(url + fileUrlArray [0]);
    console.log(res); //Error: net::ERR_ABORTED at https:myUrl/file/d/fileName.gz 

   // --------------------- Working block - but not what i want -----------

   const client = await page2.target().createCDPSession();
   await client.send("Page.setDownloadBehavior", {
      behavior: "allow",
      downloadPath: process.cwd() + "\\src\\temp",
    });
   await page2.click(`[href="${fileUrlArray[0}"]`) // it download the file

  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Error:", err.message);
    
  } finally {
    browser.close();
  }
};
```

I want to be able to read the files as stream (during the decompressing process) but its seems i can only download them (and not even read the entire file )...

Comment: It's not possible to read a file as a stream directly using Puppeteer. However, you can use Node.js's built-in fs module to read the downloaded file as a stream

Comment: @kareemAdel It's just a simple example of my requirement. I must be able to read the file as stream. cant take in account download or reading it as bulk .

Answer (score 0):

try thing like this

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const zlib = require('zlib');

async function readStreamFromUrl(url) {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error(`Failed to fetch ${url}: ${response.statusText}`);
  }
  const stream = response.body;
  return stream.pipe(zlib.createGunzip()); // decompress using gzip
}

// Usage
const url = 'https://example.com/file.gz';
const stream = await readStreamFromUrl(url);
stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
  console.log(chunk.toString());
});
```

Comment: the issue is that when i fetch to the new url , im not passing the csrf token correctly so the response will not be ok (like when i do with puppteer)